# Is Exponential Backoff inbuilt in AWS SDK Boto3?

Tags: aws-sdk, boto3, rate-limiting, exponential-backoff

I am using Mechanical Turk with Boto3 SDK.

As per the general documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html , “each AWS SDK implements exponential backoff algorithm” – so why do we need to implement it again in our code?

(I am also referring to AWS' answer here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=307015)

Answer (score 3):

Default client back-off might not be enough for every use case.

I'm not familiar with this particular service client, but you generally can detect retries by using logging level `logging.DEBUG`. It will log retry attempts, so you can check how often and how many there are.

Some services have very specific rate limits in terms of N attempts in M time, so you can override default back-off by using `botocore.config.Config` property called `retries` and constructing service client while supplying `config` keyword.

Comment: Can you clarify 'override default back-off by using botocore.config.Config property called retries'. I thought that config just helps you increase the number of retries, not anything to do with back off behavior?

Comment: There are also different modes, take a look at https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html . Maybe adaptive mode is more suited to your use case.